# Do dolphins really sleep?

Tags: sleep, mammals, aquatic-biology

I have always wondered, if dolphins sleep with one eye opened, do they really sleep at all?
According to [this article](http://science.howstuffworks.com/zoology/mammals/question643.htm) dolphins indeed *shut down* their brains.

I already googled it. No help from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unihemispheric_slow-wave_sleep) or other articles and publications found.

Comment: Of course we should note that our brain does not "shut down" (whatever that means) when we sleep.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that [unihemispheric sleep and adaptations like it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unihemispheric_slow-wave_sleep#Surfacing_for_air_and_pod_cohesion_for_marine_mammals) really are sleep - the brain activity on one side of the brain gives a characteristic sleep pattern.  It certainly must satisfy the needs of an aquatic mammal like a dolphin or a whale since they have to be partially conscious to breathe by surfacing regularly.

It does seem to affect the brain physiology, but is there a reason you would not call it sleep?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it depends on how sleep is defined. If we define it a a mechanism by which the brain repairs itself in an altered state, then, yes they do indeed sleep. Just not with all of their brain at once.